# Cambiar propiedad Type de input con Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Buenas tardes quisera que me ayuden ya que debo realizar el cambio de la propiedad de un input con Angular, he encontrado mucho con java script pero no con angular:
he hecho lo siguiente:

```
let pass=document.getElementById('password');
```

con esta linea obtengo el elemento del Dom, pero al querer cambiarle la propiedad pass.type no me sale nada y me arroja un error que no existe esa propiedad, espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app.html**

```
<input type="password" id="pass"/>

<button (click)="cambiarTipo()">cambiar tipo</button>
```

**app.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {

 cambiarTipo(){
    let elemento :any = document.getElementById('pass');
    elemento.type = "text";
  }

}
```

[Ejemplo stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-43feey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Creo que el error que mencionas es **Property 'type' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.** Eso se debe a que typescript crea por defecto un objeto de tipo `HTMLElement` y ese no tiene la propiedad `type`. Si se declara como tipo `any` ya no hay problema.